# How to convert an InputStream() to a Scanner() Java

Tags: java, file, text, inputstream

I am working on an android app so I need to use an `InputStream()` to read a txt file but I also have several methods that only work with `Scanner()` so I need a way to convert `InputStream()` to `Scanner()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open scanner for this input stream. Like that:

```
// inputStreamInstance - input stream you want to convert to scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStreamInstance);
```